# apache CXF - with xml string

Tags: web-services, cxf

I am using CXF for web services.

I have an inner xml wrapped by an outher xml.
That is, I produce an xml:

```
<aa><bb><cc>bla</cc></bb></aa>
```

and than the CXF wraps it:

```
<answer>&lt;aa&gt;&lt;bb&gt;&lt;cc&gt;bla&lt;/cc&gt;&lt;/bb&gt;&lt;/aa&gt;</answer>
```

As you can see, the `<` and `>` are escaped with `&lt;` and `&gt;`.

I wish that this doesn't happen.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is by the definition of the xml syntax.

check e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML

> - The characters "<" and "&" are key syntax markers and may never appear in content outside of a CDATA section.
> - There are five predefined entities: < represents "<", > represents ">", & represents "&", ' represents ', and " represents ".

You can try to wrap your inner xml inside a CDATA.